# Zend Framework Automatic Model Generator for Mysql

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to create a model with zf tool. But "zf  create model xxx" command is just an empty class. What must be a path to .sql file?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use Zodeken it is very good and saved my time , it is easy to use 
http://code.google.com/p/zodeken/
Hope you find wht your looking for !!!

Answer (score 1):

You may need to configure your adapter first.

Use `zf configure db-adapter` to do so.

Then you should be able to get your model skeleton ready-to-use.

Check out the [manual page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-model.html), there are all the informations you need to complete your task.

**Edit:**

```
zf configure db-adapter "adapter=PDO_MYSQL&dbname=mydb&host=localhost&username=root&password production
```

To configure your db adapter with the cli. You can also do it by hand by editing application.ini

Be sure the resources.db is set or it won't work.

Comment: I don't quite get why the manual has SQLLite in their example. Are most users really using SQL Lite? I would have thought the majority was using a standard MySQL stack.. actually I'm not sure what Zend Server installs